# Reject users script help - bash - freeradius

Tags: bash, shell, script, bash-scripting, freeradius

I have this very small script that allows users to access defined hosts, but I do not know how to reject users to access everything else:

This part of the script works fine:

```
318         Huntgroup-Name := "%{sql:SELECT groupname FROM radhuntgroup WHERE nasipaddress='%{NAS-IP-Address}'}"
```

This one does not:

```
323         elseif 
324           reject
325         }
```

Basically I just need to write something that will say deny any other access.

If anyone knows how to write that small part of the scirpt please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this:

315         update request {
316         Huntgroup-Name  := "%{sql:SELECT groupname FROM radhuntgroup WHERE nasipaddress='%{NAS-IP-Address}'}"
317 }
318         if (Huntgroup-Name == ''){
319         reject
320         }